# how to crop canvas from video and save as image?

Tags: video, canvas

how to crop canvas from video and save as image?
Im using this

```
function capture(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var video = document.getElementById('video');
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight); }
```

and the html is

```
<v ideo id="video" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" controls></video><br/>

<button onclick="capture()">Capture</button> <br/><br/>
<canvas class="input" id="canvas"></canvas> <br/><br/>
```

its getting a image as canvas. but now how to save as image? i tried with Filesaver.js
but i dont know how to save as image from canvas with this code.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("my-canvas"), ctx == canvas.getContext("2d");
// draw to canvas...
canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
saveAs(blob, "pretty image.png");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the below code on *click event of download*:

```
this.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
this.download = 'pretty_image.jpeg';
```

Comment: To Ashish ... Thank you for "stealing" my (approved) suggested edit in revision 2 ... You performed a rollback of them (in revision 3), and then in revision 4 you edited your answer ... by reusing 95% of my suggested edit ... That is ***not*** nice, which is also why i flagged your answer ... Can I get my "+2" rep points back somehow please? PS to @Bhargav : merci for the re-rollback, too bad it doesn't return me the +2 again ... Oh well, so be it ...